# jQuery: Selecting by data- attribute fails for some elements - why?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Given that HTML code:

```
<div id="details" data-type="motion">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" data-type="motion" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidun...</p>
```

Why is the selector of the following script not working properly?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('[data-type="motion"]').each(function() {

        $this = $(this);

        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {

            var yOffset = (window.pageYOffset / $this.data('speed')) + 'px';

            $this.css({'border': '1px solid red'});
        });

    });

});
```

Using `'[data-type="motion"]'`, only the image gets selected.`'div[data-type="motion"]'` of course only selects the div with that data-attribute. `'*[data-type="motion"]'` also only matches the image & `'img[data-type="motion"], div[data-type="motion"]'` seems kind of redundant and is also not working.

Here is a Fiddle demonstrating that behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7QXn/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not the selector, it's the local variable that isn't local:

```
$this = $(this);
```

This will create a global variable, so the event handler for each element will affect the last element.

Make it a local variable:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML:

```
<div id="details" data-type="motion">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" data-type="motion" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidun...</p>
```

The `$this.data('speed')` fails, as there is no element with `data-speed=""`.

And also you need to change the variable this way for scope:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Comment: Although your point is 100% corect, the other answer solved my issue. This is what happens when you try to simplify the test-case during lunch ;-)

Comment: Ha ha... I actually added the other thing and went to snack.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be done this way: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7QXn/4/)

```
    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        $('[data-type="motion"]').each(function () {
            $this = $(this);
            var yOffset = (window.pageYOffset / $this.data('speed')) + 'px';
            $this.css({
                'border': '1px solid red'
            });
        });
    });
```